# How to get Page Name given Page ID in Oracle Application Express

Tags: database-design, plsql, oracle-12c, metadata, oracle-apex

**Prefix:** I have looked all over the net for this answer. Let me prefix the question by describing what I am trying to do: I am trying to create a *unique list* of shortcuts to pages in my application for *each user*. So I am wanting to use a dynamic list to query for shortcut list. I already have procedures in place and ready to get the user ID and the page ID. I am using apex 5.0

**The Question:** What is the *table* and *column* (if it even exists) I need to query for in order to get the page name if given the corresponding page ID. ie:

```
select UNKNOWN_COLUMN_FOR_APEX_PAGE_NAME 
from UNKNOWN_TABLE_FOR_APEX_PAGE_INFO
```

**Alternate Question:** Is there an apex global variable like :APEX_USER or :APEX_PAGE_ID that I can use to get the page name/title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you want (and a lot more) is available in the view `APEX_050000.APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES`

```
SYS@mydb01> describe apex_050000.APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES
Name                        Null?    Type
--------------------------- -------- -------------------------------------
WORKSPACE                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)
WORKSPACE_DISPLAY_NAME               VARCHAR2(4000)
APPLICATION_ID              NOT NULL NUMBER
APPLICATION_NAME            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)
PAGE_ID                     NOT NULL NUMBER
PAGE_NAME                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)
PAGE_TITLE                           VARCHAR2(255)
PAGE_MODE                            VARCHAR2(16)
...
PAGE_ALIAS                           VARCHAR2(255)
```

And a sample query would be

```
select WORKSPACE, APPLICATION_NAME, 
   PAGE_ID, PAGE_NAME, PAGE_TITLE, PAGE_MODE 
from  APEX_050000.APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES
where workspace  = 'MY_WS' and page_id=210;
```

There is a built-in substitution string APP_PAGE_ID and APP_ID, so you could do this in your page to use the current page ID and application ID to get the page title:

```
select PAGE_TITLE from APEX_050000.APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES
where PAGE_ID = :APP_PAGE_ID and APPLICATION_ID = :APP_ID;
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_sub.htm#BEIIBAJD for all the built-in substitution strings.